# How can I conditionally output the short author in my beamer footline?

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I have a footline where I want to output the authors name, but it is perfectly legitimate to not pass the authors name and hence the `\insertshortauthor` macro can be empty. The problem is we use `|` in our template to separate the data fields, therefore I need to know if the field actually prints something.

To my understanding, the `\beamer@shortauthor` macro is only defined, after `\author` was called, at least I do not see it defined outside `beamerbasetitle.sty`, where it reads:

```
\def\author{\@dblarg\beamer@author}
\long\def\beamer@author[#1]#2{%
  \def\insertauthor{\def\inst{\beamer@insttitle}\def\and{\beamer@andtitle}#2}%
  \def\beamer@shortauthor{#1}%
  \ifbeamer@autopdfinfo%
    \def\beamer@andstripped{}%
    \beamer@stripands#2 \and\relax
    {\let\inst=\@gobble\let\thanks=\@gobble\def\and{, }\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\beamer@andstripped}}}
  \fi%
}
```

and hence I don't get, why I can't just check if `\beamer@shortauthor` was defined yet. At least my MWE whcih reads:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\ifdefined\beamer@shortauthor\insertshortauthor~|~\else No author given\fi Some more information}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \frame{No author given yet, footline should say so but does not}
    \author{Author}
    \frame{Author given now, footline is good}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't work as expected, the `\ifdefined` does not consider `\beamer@shortauthor` to ever be undefined. How can I check if there will be a short author or not to decide if I need to output the `~|~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that line 167 of `beamerbasetitle.sty` contains `\author{}`, hence `\beamer@shortauthor` is always defined and initially empty, and one can/should test if meaningful `\author{...}` is used by `\ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty`.

The following example outputs

- "No author given Some more information" on first frame, and
- "Author | Some more information" on second frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty
    No author given
  \else
    \leavevmode\insertshortauthor~|~%
  \fi
  Some more information%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \frame{No author given yet, footline should say so but does not}
    \author{Author}
    \frame{Author given now, footline is good}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works great, I didn't think about the possibility that `\author{}` is called elsewhere.